# Using grunt-contrib-connect - open page URL with added context path

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I have set up grunt connect like this:

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        hostname: 'localhost'
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            open: true,
            base: [
                'app'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

That works great - loads my index.html page as:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

However, to keep this consistent with how it will be loaded in production, I would like it to load it with additional context path added, like:

```
http://localhost:9000/myappcontext/secured
```

Can this be done simply with grunt-contrib-connect? Or do I need to add some other proxy/middleware?

Anyone got a simple example of this type of set-up?

Comment: were you using grunt-contrib-watch to handle the live reload?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do this without much trouble, just configure the `open` option:

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        hostname: 'localhost'
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            open: {
                 target: 'http://localhost:9000/myappcontext/secured'
            },
            base: [
                'app'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[You can consult the README for more information about the available options.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#open)

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but it attempts to load my index.html file from the file system at /app/myappcontext/secured/index.html - but my index.html file is /app/index.html.  Do I need to use connect-rewrite in conjunction with the above suggested set-up?

Comment: Seems it does need a rewrite. I managed to get this working following the example here: https://github.com/viart/grunt-connect-rewrite - with at rule like: { from: '^/myappcontext/secured/(.*)$', to: '/$1' }

Comment: Ah yes, it will host your index.html at the root unless you do something, if you mount a folder like I did, it wont be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rewrite middleware rules to load from a different context-root https://github.com/viart/http-rewrite-middleware

This would work in your scenario:

```
    var rewriteModule = require('http-rewrite-middleware');
    middlewares.push(rewriteModule.getMiddleware([
        //Load App under context-root of 'myappcontext/secured'
        {from: '^/myappcontext/secured(.*)$', to: '/$1'},

        //Redirect slash to myappcontext/secured as convenience
        {from: '^/$', to: '/myappcontext/secured', redirect: 'permanent'},

        //Send a 404 for anything else
        {from: '^/.+$', to: '/404'}
    ]));
```

Comment: The new version seems to come with middleware. Can that be used somehow? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/#middleware - Can't figure it out from the usage examples though.

Comment: @Rhys yes, you could use that to write your own function to do the rewriting, but http-rewrite-middleware implements the specific rewrite functionality in a way that is easily reused. Middleware is just nodejs nomenclature for filtering of a request/response. You can see in the code how it works https://github.com/viart/http-rewrite-middleware/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I have one stupid method, but it's a method !

```
    copy: {
        "mount-server": {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: './.mount-server/myappcontext/secured/',    // your expected path here
                src: [
                    '**/**'
                ]
            }]
        }
    }

    open: {
        server: {
            path: 'http://localhost:9000/myappcontext/secured/index.html'
        }

    }

    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 80,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: null
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect, options) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, "./.mount-server/")
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    grunt.registerTask('prepareServer', [
        "clean:mount-server",
        "copy:mount-server"
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {

        grunt.task.run([
            'concurrent:server',
            'prepareServer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open:server',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With this being a fairly dated post, I thought I'd share what I had to do since some of the libraries are out of date with even the libraries referenced. Also this shows the entire process, rather than piecemealing the comments.

The example in the library https://github.com/viart/grunt-connect-rewrite is using a very dated version of grunt-contrib-connect

*From version 0.11.x, the new grunt-contrib-connect does not support connect.static and connect.directory. You need to use another library `serve-static`*

```
var rewriteRulesSnippet = require('grunt-connect-rewrite/lib/utils').rewriteRequest,
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: true //default port is 35729
    },
    rules: [
        { from: '^/yourfolder/(.*)$', to: '/$1' }
    ],
    server: {
        options: {
            base: './app', //where the files are served from
            open: {
                 target: 'http://localhost:9000/yourfolder'
            },
            middleware: function(connect, options) {
                return [
                    rewriteRulesSnippet, // RewriteRules support
                    serveStatic(options.base[0]) // new library used here
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this setup but it didn't seem to work unfortunately. I think the setup might have changed since. Server seems to be the parent then options. Not sure where to put rules. I have tried pretty much every combo but no luck yet.